# Constantly CMS executing after reaching OccupancyFraction limit

Tags: java, garbage-collection

For our application we are using **Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_66-b17)** and the **following JVM settings:**

> -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:InitialHeapSize=32212254720 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=32212254720 -XX:MaxNewSize=4294967296 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6 -XX:NewSize=4294967296 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC

I noticed via GCViewer that after reaching 75% using of tenured generation, "Concurrent Collection" execution is invoking almost constantly(every minute) without any real cleaning.

I would expect if CMS cannot clean memory then full gc will be executed. Unfortunately I cannot find info about such behaviour in public sources.
Could you please help me with better understanding of this process.

Comment: Why do you expect that?

Answer (score 0):

With CMS collector, Full GC would usually be triggered by "Concurrent Mode Failure", meaning that as long as the collector can catch up with its garbage, there's no need to call the "big guy".